# i need to take a select value and pass it to php variable

Tags: php, html, html-select

i stuck with this. I want to replace an editbox if a form with a select options. I have the following code that i use to take the valuefrom the editbox

```
<input type="text" name="toheat" size="30" class="inputbox" maxlength="50" value="<?php     echo $obj->toheat; ?>" />
```

How can i do it so the user can choose from certen 2-3 options?
Can you give me a clue how to continue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a select box in the form :

```
<select name="toheat" id="toheat">
        <option value="">select</option>
       <option value="toHeat1" <?php if($obj->toheat == "toHeat1"){?> selected="selected" <?php } ?>>toHeat1Name</option> 
       <option value="toHeat2" >toHeat2Name</option>
       //and so on
    </select>
```

I hope this can be of some help